# which JDK is installed

Tags: java

On RHEL 6 64 bit, first I installed openJDK via yum and later I could validate the same by running `rpm -qa | grep jdk`

Later, I removed the openjdk and downloaded the Oracle jdk. Oracle gave me a `.bin` file which is a slef extraclter and installed java.

**QUESTION:** Now, how do I verify by looking at the installed java that this is coming from the oracle JDK and not the openJDK.

BTW, oracle provides a rpm for their JDK, but I chose to install it using .bin file.

Moderators, please move my question to superuser if you feel so. I chose to post on stack overflow as we have numerous Java programmers here who would easily know the answer.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I already had run those commands but is does not say anything specific to Oracle:

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

# javac -version
javac 1.6.0_45

# which java
/usr/bin/java

# whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java

# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java
```

Comment: Open a terminal, and write `javac -version`, it will tell you if it's oracle jdk or openjdk and the version too.

Comment: or from code, as this is SO: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

Comment: HotSpot is Oracle's Java SE implementation (apart from JRockit).

Answer (score 4):

First use `which javac` to see which binary is beeing used.

Then simply run `javac -version` to see which version you are running.

If the output mentions

> Java HotSpot(TM)

Then it is most likely Oracle Java SDK.

Comment: I would recommend using `javac` instead of `java` as others stated in comments. Note that the JRE can differ from the JDK in case you (or another person) installed a different JRE.